# Export Excel data with a custom deliminator in .csv

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I want to export a huge excel file as a .csv, but the data contains commas within the cells.

How do I export the excel data to a .csv with the deliminator as this |

I've tried doing the usual "save as", but it is not working for my data.

Comment: This is probably better suited for www.SuperUser.com

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21456/export-or-save-excel-files-with-pipe-or-other-delimiters-instead-of-commas/

Comment: Why change the delimiter? What is wrong with quote marks around the comma-containing entries?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Using the data in a python program, and quotes are also used in the data

Comment: Again, why change the delimiter?  The are rules for CSV files that contain commas and quotes within a single field. Does python not respect those rules when reading the file?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I'm parsing the data line by line from the csv file, separating everything and getting rid of everything I don't need

Comment: Then just modify your parser to follow the rules for csv files.  One example of the rules is [The Comma Separated Value File Format](http://www.creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm)

Comment: And if you have code that is not functioning as you wish, edit your question to include the code, sample of data, actual output and desired output. Consider reviewing [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I don't have a parsing module, I parse it myself because I need more control over it. Dealing with a unique deliminator is the path of least resistance for my project. And yes I know how to ask a good question and have reviewed it before you linked the article. The information I needed was what my question asks, I do not need help developing python code. I have functioning code which only works with CSV's delimited with pipes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158347/discussion-between-ron-rosenfeld-and-spybug96).

Comment: @User91504 This is the answer I'm going with if you want to make it an answer, because it gets me to where I want to be and works perfectly to the specifications of my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi Check out this method in the below link, its what I have used in the past

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21456/export-or-save-excel-files-with-pipe-or-other-delimiters-instead-of-commas/

**Summary:**

Control Panel –> Region and Language, and then click the Additional settings

When in the additional settings find “List separator”

Change this to anything you want, in your case you would want the | pipe

Comment: office 365 excel as of 20200724 - this solution does not work :(

Comment: For Windows 10 as of August 2021 the "Region and Language" group is named "Clock and Region" so the path to the setting is: Control Panel > Clock and Region > Additional Settings > List separator

Comment: how to do it in macos?

Comment: This actually worked for me, lol. And thanks for the updated location, @sezmeralda !

Answer (score -1):

By definition CSV stands for Comma Delimited.

Easy alternatives that were under your nose in the Save As window are:

"Formatted Text(Space Delimited)" though this won't be appropriate if you have spaces in your cells

"Text(Tab Delimited)" it is less likely you'll have tabs in your cells and people won't type those in to excel.

If you really want the 'pipe' | then I would suggest saving as tab delimited and running some kind of find & replace on the resulting text file. This is a bit of a workaround

A even bigger workaround is to concatenate the cells using a formula on the sheet with a | involved and the save as text only that column.

Comment: "By definition CSV stands for Comma Delimited." 

Correct, but Excel invalidates this definition by setting the delimiter to some regional settings. I.e. in some countries you will end up with semicolon delimiter :(

Comment: To be fair, for languages where comma's are used as a decimal separator, it does not make sense to use it as a separator.

Comment: I mean - the standard allows quoting to get around that issue. I.e: "2,00",monkey,"3,73",carrots,etc  I believe that excel has ruined what should be one of the simplest file types, with the delimiter right in the description.